# Can I say Nodejs is like JVM but for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js

**JAVA** runs in JVM.
**JavaScript** runs in NodeJS.

Okay.

So, can I say that NodeJS is like JVM but for JavaScript ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) (you get a badge!) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research, post a [Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and specifically say where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: You can if you want to.

Comment: Hi, this probably isn't the best type of question for StackOverflow as it's bit more opinion based and there is no 'correct' answer. That said, I probably wouldn't describe it like that. NodeJS is, 99% of time, just a way of running javascript for a server without needing a client browser. A JVM is more like a common virtual operating system that allows Java to run smoothly regardless of the hosting environment.

Comment: It seems like a JVM is more like V8.  Each can run the bytecode from the appropriate language and they manage and garbage collect memory used by the language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't, NodeJS is a utility wrapper (and really a necessary one) over [Google's V8 engine](https://v8.dev), Google's JavaScript runtime.

There are also other issues with this statement as Java is compiled to its own byte code (although you could argue that this would be WASM or V8 bytecode) and JavaScript is interpreted.

Despite these differences, NodeJS is like JRE for JS in a practical sense.

Comment: That would make NodeJS the equivalent of a JRE.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- You are right (Haven't worked with Java in a long time)